# jQuery dialog box not showing in the center

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having the same issue as i had in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639360/jquery-dialog-box-not-in-center-in-chrome) but now for all browsers.

Here is the code:

```
$('form#main').live('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = this;
        ////console.log('click submit')
        var $div = $('<div>', {
            html: 'Are you sure you want to submit this table?<br/> All undo information will be lost.'
        }).dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Are You Sure?',
            buttons: {
                ok: function() {
                    self.console('clicked ok');
                    $.post($this.action, $($this).serialize() + '&page=' + self.pageOn, function(data) {
                        self.console(data);
                        $('.DEV-time').text("  (File last updated at: " + data.DEV + ")");
                        $('.PROD-time').text("  (File last updated at: " + data.PROD + ")");
                        if(data.ERROR.length > 0){
                            alert(data.ERROR);
                        }
                        self.pageChanged = false;
                        self.origPage = $('#page').clone();
                        self.lastClick = $('#page').clone();
                    }, 'json')
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            beforeClose: function() {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        })

        $div.dialog('widget').css('margin', '0 auto');

        return false;
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REMOVING** the:

```
$div.dialog('widget').css('margin', '0 auto');
```

which  was the [**fix**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639360/jquery-dialog-box-not-in-center-in-chrome#answer-5639881) to the last question, fixed it this time

Comment: Btw, you have a missing ; when closing the dialog definition, right before the line you just removed.

Comment: @eagerMoose, there is no need for it

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 'margin', you need to give it an explicit css width.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the .dialog() method doesn't know content height before it loads. Either try defining height in dialog definition, or try this [Centering jQuery UI dialog of unknown height - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474350/centering-jquery-ui-dialog-of-unknown-height-is-it-possible)

EDIT: sorry, I didn't see it was about centering it horizontally. If so, you probably need to explicitly set the width of the dialog, or use the same trick as above in the link.

Comment: now i noticed that it is centered in IE, but not in FF and Chrome, and it is of known height...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle example and post it here?

Answer (score -1):

have you import/include the position.js? on your code?

```
<script src="jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
```

it's work for me